# want to access local Ubuntu server to get files to hosting

Tags: server, command-line, hosting

I do have local Ubuntu server with files, I need to access those files and upload them to my website hosting. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean you can use filezilla to upload files to an external hosting site if you have the username and password that was supplied by the hosting site.

Or if you are suggesting that you would like to point the hosting site to your local computer then you will want to open your firewall with ufw and do some port forwarding on your router. Which would entail opening a browser and navigating to the router admin page something like ( `http://192.168.0.1` )

If you mean that you would like to host files from your ubuntu server then there are several methods to do this.

1. You could set up your own SFTP service.
2. You could use [openSSH-server](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html), or
3. you could use [apache](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) to
   serve files over http.

Answer (score 0):

The GNU/Linux operating system is commonly used among Web hosting providers. If you manage a website, mailing list, discussion forum, or database, then your data quite likely flows through a Linux system on its way to your users. In order to change your content quickly on a Linux system, you must have a reliable way to copy your files to it. The Secure Copy protocol, or SCP, is the standard protocol for copying files to Linux systems such as Ubuntu.